# Material-UI AutoComplete Grouping logic does not honor duplicates

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am encountering a problem in grouping. Tried to sort it but what I need to grouped are data with nested children on it. And I wanted it to be grouped by its parent node. Would this be possible using AutoComplete?

data is like as follows:

```
[{
  name: "1"
  parent: null
      children: [
        {
          name: "1.1"
          parent: "1"
        },
        {
         name: "1.2"
         parent: "1"
       }
      ]
}]
```

with this kind of data it shows this error:

```
Material-UI: The options provided combined with the groupBymethod of Autocomplete returns duplicated headers. You can solve the issue by sorting the options with the output ofgroupBy.
```

Is there a way for me to have no duplicates and group them all by their specified parent?

Answer (score 3):

You need to sort the option array (`data[0].children` in your case) using the label you want to use in `groupBy`.

```
const options = data[0].children
const sortedOptions = options.sort((a, b) => a.parent > b.parent? 1 : -1))
```

Comment: "If you do so, make sure that the options are also sorted with the same dimension that they are grouped by, otherwise, you will notice duplicate headers."
SRC: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#grouped

Answer (score 1):

Extract children array from each element, then concatenate all children on one array and pass this array as `groupBy` argument, since each element of the children has parent prop.

To be like this:

#### Options

```js
[
  {
    name: '1.1',
    parent: '1'
  },
  {
    name: '1.2',
    parent: '1'
  },
  {
    name: '2.1',
    parent: '2'
  },
  {
    name: '3.1',
    parent: '3'
  },
  {
    name: '3.2',
    parent: '3'
  }
];
```

#### `groupBy`

```js
groupBy={(option) => option.parent}
```